# Imputation of a variable with missing data conditional on another variable in R

Tags: r, missing-data, conditional

I have a medical data set with missing data in few variables. But on carefully observing, missingness of some variables are dependent on the response of another variable. For example, "age at when become pregnant" has missing data. But many of them are missing / not entered as this question does not make sense for male participants. Hence, this missingness is conditional on gender - you can only mark the age in years in females and not in males.
In such cases, how to impute the real missing data - female gender and age at pregnancy is missing and not in cases of male gender.
I use `mice` package in R a lot, but unable to find a correct solution.
I cannot model such dataset without imputation - many of the conventional as well as AI models need complete dataset. I will end up having only few rows of data if I use "complete cases" option.
Need help...